# Additional dweller stuck in the vault entrance?

Tags: fallout-shelter

What will happen now? He is supposed to be in a quest... 
[image]

[image]

Comment: In about four hours you can write an answer for us.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. Tell us what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Really? The timer is on there. He is travelling to the mission. It will take 3 hrs 50 mins. That is why he hasn't left yet. He will do the mission, it is just a graphical bug.